# How to preserve spaces in args when running $@ with eval

Tags: bash, arguments

I'm writing a bash script that runs everything passed to it. I want it to work like so:

```bsh
$ ./myscript.sh echo hello world
# should run 'echo hello world'
```

This is my script thus far:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

eval "$@"
```

This works fine with the above example:

```bsh
$ ./myscript.sh echo hello world
# successfully runs `echo hello world`
```

But if any of the passed arguments have spaces, it doesn't work correctly, because the spaces get broken up into multiple arguments:

```bsh
$ ./myscript.sh sh -c 'echo hello world'
# runs `sh -c 'echo' 'hello' 'world'` instead of `sh -c 'echo hello world'`, so nothing is printed
```

How can I pass all the arguments a bash script receives to eval without interpreting the spaces in them at all?

Comment: Why do you need the `eval`? Just `"$@"` should work fine for the examples shown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What good does `eval` give you in this case? Use this:

```
"$@"
```

i.e. `eval "$@"`.

If you still think you need `eval` then this:

```
eval "${@@Q}"
```

`${var@Q}` makes Bash quote and/or escape the content, so after being parsed again (and this is what `eval` does) it comes to its original state. `${var@Q}` is helpful if the content must be parsed (e.g. you pass it via `ssh` to a remote shell you cannot avoid). If you can avoid extra parsing then do avoid. In your case you do this by not using `eval`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56104052/10765659) notices `@Q` in Bash is not perfect.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I could just put "$@" on a line by itself.